# How to call a directive and return result from it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is code, I want to calculate the height of a div. I have created some code need help in it. How can I call `myDirective` and return result to a particular div

**My directive,**

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          var sectioHeight=angular.element(document.querySelector('#header'))[0].offsetHeight;
            console.log(angular.element(document.querySelector('#header'))[0].offsetHeight);

        }
    };
  });
```

**View section,**

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
  <div id="header">//In this section I want that height
    <h1 my-directive>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <h1 my-directive>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <h1 my-directive>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div>
</body>
```

Comment: A directive doesn't typically "return" anything...

Comment: So is it possible to calculate height of a particular div without directive

Comment: You're going to do *what* with that calculated height...?

Comment: I need to set CSS property after a particular height

Comment: So what you want in this case is to specify a controller in the header directive which is a requirement by your myDirective. You can then call the controller from myDirectives link function after it has rendered. Problem will be that it initially reports 0.

Comment: I s it possible to call a controller after page load and calculate height of a particular div by its class name ?